# Adding extra properties to AbpTenant in Abp Framework

Tags: abp

I want to add some properties to tenant (customer for us) like taxno, email, phone.
Should I add new columns to AbpTenant table (and should I create AbpTenant App Service for manage) or should I create a new table (for ex.: named as customer) which refers to abpTenant via tenant_id.

I could not understand why/when should I use extraproperties column (which is contained by many table).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can follow this [documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Customizing-Application-Modules-Extending-Entities) to extend prebuild modules/entites.

But, you must wait for 3.1 release because ABP team applied the **module extension system** to some free modules (identity, tenant-management etc.) just few weeks before (in 3.1 version development cycle).

After 3.1 release, you can add new properties easily to `Tenant` entity. You will declare your entity extension property and it will appear in UI also.

Here is a spoiler image for you. :) This image is for users but `Tenant` entity has also same feature.

[image]